# Sorting a circular list of binary necklaces by rotational hamming distance

Tags: python, sorting, number-theory, hamming-distance, information-theory

I am trying to sort lists of binary necklaces in circle format.
So that elements on the opposite side of the circle have the greatest max rotational hamming distance. And neighbors have the smallest.

I am hopping around the circle adding up the rotational max hamming distance.
I test all permutations and select the permutation with the small total hamming distance around the circumference.

All fine and dandy but permutations get to be too much calculation for n>9
I want to run this on n=66, for example.

So I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to sort the circle according to my criteria. All necklaces are of equal length.

here my code:

```
import sys
import itertools
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming

def rotate(strg, n):
    return strg[n:] + strg[:n]

def combinantorial(lst):
    count = 0
    index = 1
    pairs = []
    for element1 in lst:
        for element2 in lst[index:]:
            pairs.append((element1, element2))
        index += 1

def permute(items):
    length = len(items)
    def inner(ix=[]):
        do_yield = len(ix) == length - 1
        for i in range(0, length):
            if i in ix: #avoid duplicates
                continue
            if do_yield:
                yield tuple([items[y] for y in ix + [i]])
            else:
                for p in inner(ix + [i]):
                    yield p
    return inner()



def maxhammer(list1, list2):
    themaxham = 0
    hamcheck = 0

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        hamcheck = hamming(list(list1),list(rotate(list2, i)))*len(list(list1));
        if hamcheck > themaxham:
            themaxham = hamcheck
    return themaxham


lines_list = map(str.strip, sys.stdin);


permutationslist = permute(lines_list[1:])

minlength = 999999;
linecount = 0;


for line in permutationslist:
    listtemp = list(line)
    listtemp.insert(0, lines_list[0])
    line = tuple(listtemp)
    circlelength = 0;
    for i in range(len(line)):
        circlelength+= maxhammer(line[i], line[(i+1)%len(line)])
    if circlelength < minlength:
        minlength = circlelength
        winner = line
        print(line)
        print("CIRCLELENGTH:",circlelength)
print("WINNER:")
print(winner)
```

I run it like so:

```
cat lyndonlist.txt | grep -x '.\{5\}'  python minmaxhamBRUTEFORCE.py
```

This will send all 5 bit Lyndon words in to the program

output:

```
('10000', '11000', '10100', '11100', '11010', '11110')
('CIRCLELENGTH:', 22.0)
('10000', '11000', '10100', '11100', '11110', '11010')
('CIRCLELENGTH:', 20.0)
('10000', '11000', '11010', '11110', '11100', '10100')
('CIRCLELENGTH:', 18.0)
WINNER:
('10000', '11000', '11010', '11110', '11100', '10100')
```

This gives me a cycle of words with lexicographic opposites on the opposite sides of the cycle.

Here is a diagram of the winning output:

[The Elements with rotational Hamming Max between each shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxGxk.jpg)

Comment: So roughly speaking: A circular table, enemies on opposite sides of the table and friends adjacent, as much as possible.  So from the stand point of any member, a walk around the table will steadily increase the "enemy factor" until they get to opposite side where it is maximal, and then the "enemy factor" will decrease as they return to their chair.

Comment: Enemy = high rotational hamming max.  
Friend = low.
Rotational Hamming Max mean you compare Hamming Distance for all rotations of a string and select the Max... So 11010 and 01010 will score 5, and 110 and 111 will score 1.. Actually now that I think of it I should check friend with Rotational Hamming MIN, and enemies with Rotational Hamming MAX...

Comment: I have an idea how to approach this, but I need a more rigorous description of the scoring function.  "minimal rotational hamming distance between adjacent neighbors" and "maximal rotational hamming distance between opposing pairs" are two distinct metrics, and the optimal solution for one may not be optimal for the other.

Comment: The paper "On the traveling salesman problem in binary Hamming spaces" is pretty close to what you're looking for.  The paper itself may be enlightening, and at the very least, some of its references (particularly [4], [6], and [9]) are particularly relevant.

Comment: Minimal rotational hamming distance means: 
I take a pair of equal length strings, s1, s2. 
I calculate hamming(s1,rot(s2,x)) for x in range(len(s1))
Keep the lowest scored result.  
I am trying to optimize the result set such that the total Rotational hamming minimum of all adjacent members is minimized.
"opposing pairs" means on the opposite side of the "table".  So if we had 30 members, index 0 and index 16 would be opposing pairs. For the opposing pairs I calculate hamming(s1,rot(s2,x)) for x in range(len(s1))
Keep the highest scored result, maximize total opposing max rot ham dist.

Comment: That part makes sense, but how do you aggregate the scores to a single value? Do you sum the hamming distances of neighbors? Sum the hamming distance of opposing pairs? Take the min of those two sums? Max? Add them?  We effectively have a list of scores between pairs (adjacent and opposing) and need to reduce this to a single value, so we can declare a maximum / minimum. We can negate the score of the opposing pairs so that we minimize (rather than maximize) that, but I still need a formula to reduce it to a single value

Comment: Consider, just as an example, the case where we get back `(adjacent_list, opposing_list)` pair scores-  `([1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3])` and for another arrangement, `([2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5])` the first is "better" in that it has lower scores for adjacent pairs, but the latter is "better" because it has higher scores (distances) for opposing pairs.  We could even have the issue such as `([1, 1, 1, 9], [...])` vs `([2, 2, 2, 2], [...])` the second sums smaller, but the first is typically smaller / better scoring, with one outlier.  These are why we need a concrete formula to reduce it to a single value.

Comment: I have been minimizing total rotational hamming distance for neighbors and maximizing for members on the opposite side of the circle.  I evaluate permutations of the arrange of the circle of values.  If get a new low for total min ham distance, that permutation goes into the winner's slot. If get a tie for the total min ham distance I check if the max ham total for opposite pairs is higher and if so , then we have a new winner.  If you look at the attached diagram you can see the edges around the hexagon (circle) have maxrotham of 3 while the the score for members on the opposite side is 5

Comment: Yeah I can see why a single value would be better.  For my application the lowest total neighbor hamming distance  is the priority.  I am thinking to use maximal hamming distance on the opposites side as a tie-breaker, and because I suspect a strong relationship between the 2 comparisons in the case of my dataset.  But I still haven't managed an algorithm that terminates.

Comment: I've been thinking this problem over on & off over the last week, and I'm pretty sure there's not going to be a polynomial time solution. If you're okay with approximate solutions, we can get something that's guaranteed within 50% of the optimal which is polynomial time, and can possibly improve that with some probabilistic manipulations., but that's about it.

Comment: You'll almost certainly need to use some general-purpose TSP solver. Your particular variant seems to be a complete, (sym)metric, integer weight TSP. It is **not** euclidean, however.

Comment: I've been experimenting with simulated annealing.  I can get a perfect neighbor score, and am gradually bringing up the opposite score tweaking some of the initial parameters.  But I think I need to adjust the way the list gets shaken up. I will put in a function that reversing a segment of the list while simultaneously reversing  the segment on the other side of the circle.  Each test runs 1-3 hours so I've been running on various google cloud instances to save time.  For now I'm tweaking parameters by hand.

Comment: You can find all perfect neighbor arrangements using dynamic programming for TSP, it'll run in `O(n^2 * 2^n)` time, however.  So it may be doable for ~20-30 members, depending how optimized the implementation is.

Comment: 66 member is a requirement, I am arranging the 66 types of 7 note musical scales (assuming 12 note octave).   I had a thought that I might be able to tweak the Lyndon word generation algorithm so that it spits out the words I need in the desired order.. probably a long shot.